# Random access file

Tags: c#

I have created a login form application, the form has two text box one accepts the username the other one accepts a password, usernames and passwords have been stored in a text file called "Registered.txt" the form also has a button called login, I want my program to be able to read the "Registered.txt" file to check if the password or username enter is valid if the users clicks login using a random access file.

Comment: Which part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any attempts? Can you show some your code samples and specify what is going wrong?

Comment: "..usernames and passwords have been stored in a text file..." Good idea :) Provide some code.. it will help us to help you...

Comment: Reading from a text file

Comment: I am having a problem with reading from a text file to check if the username or password do exist in the text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give an example and hope it will help you get what you want.

In this example your Registered.txt file should look like:
Smartsasse,myPassword
OlofBoll,P@ssword

```
//var path = @"C:\Registered.txt";
var path = "Registered.txt";

var allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

var userInfo = allLines.Select(l => l.Split(',')).Select(s => new
{
    Username = s[0],
    Password = s[1]
}).ToList();

var user = userInfo.FirstOrDefault(ui => ui.Username.ToLowerInvariant() == this.UserNameTextBox.Text.Trim().ToLowerInvarant());

if (user != null && user.Password == this.PasswordTextBox)
{
    // Login is okay
    this.ViewState["loggedInUser"] = user.Username;
}
else
{
    // Show error message
    throw new Exception("Couldn't login, invalid username or password.");
}
```

You will need to reference "System.Linq" by "using System.Linq;". If not you could change some of the code to:

```
bool success = false;
foreach (var line in allLines)
{
    var username = line.Split(',')[0];
    var password = line.Split(',')[1];

    if (username == this.UserNameTextBox.Text && password == this.PasswordTextBox.Text)
    {
        // Login
        // this.ViewState["loggedInUser"] = user.Username;
        success = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (success == false)
{
    // Show error
    throw new Exception("Couldn't login, invalid username or password.");
}
```

This code will not run just by it self but might help you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Edi G. mentioned in comments - it's very bad idea to store usernames and passwords in plain text file. Security of such approach is absolutely zero.

But if you still want to try - here some guidance.

To read text data from file you need to create `FileStream` pointing to your file and `StreamReader` to read from that stream.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"path_to_your_file\Registered.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            // do your checks here

            line = reader.ReadLine();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's very bad practice to store usernames and passwords in a text file but the security doesn't need to be "absolute zero" since you can restrict access to the file and just becuase it is a plain text file the information in it can be encrypted. But yeah, still very bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers you guys are the best thank you very much

Comment: @Sasse Well, in this situation restricting of read access to file is impossible, as program need to read from it and program is running under some user's credentials. So that user will be able to read from file. :) So only encryption wil help, but it's out of OP's question scope.

Comment: @Andy: Yeah but the file might be on a server that only you have access too, then you can have the file protected by others then you own program. An unencrypted textfile might be as protected as a database, not all databases are encrypted.